# Printing boxes pattern in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to print 2 boxes like given in this figure: 
[image]

I tried the below program but it is not giving the expected output.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Considering each box as a separate one
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {           
    cout << "+---+ " << endl;
    cout << "|  " << i << "| " << endl;
    cout << "|   | " << endl;
    cout << "|   | " << endl;
    cout << "+---+ ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting:

```
+---+ 
|  1| 
|   | 
|   | 
+---+ +---+ 
|  2| 
|   | 
|   | 
+---+
```

Please help me where I am missing things. 
Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @downvoter, I tried my best but unable to find the solution. Please tell me the reason for downvoting

Comment: I suggest you post what you got. Also note that your boxes are printed on the same line (first line for example is `+---+ +---+`, all in one line.

Comment: If you want to use plain `std::cout` you won't find a solution to print the boxes seperately. Try to print the first row of both boxes instead, continue with the second row for both boxes, and so forth...

Comment: @wolff, I wish I could go by the rows but I can't because each box has to be treated separately.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla the reason for downvoting was probably that you did not show the output of your current attempt and that you did not elaborate further what you expected.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Maybe you could try to write a function `draw(int boxID, int row)`, which draws only one row of a box. By this you could treat the boxes seperately, yet being able to draw them side by side.

Comment: You can use a library, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses. Using cout will not scale very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logically trace through your for-loop, you'd see how you print one box at a time, stacked on top of the other.

You need to ensure that you print the tops of all the boxes on the same line, then move on to the bodies of all the boxes, and so on, until all boxes have been printed "in parallel".

To do this, you could print each line within its own for-loop. For example:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) cout << "+---+ ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) cout << "|  " << i << "| ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) cout << "|   | ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) cout << "|   | ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) cout << "+---+ ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't consider each box as a separate one because you are printing them as characters into a terminal which is done line by line. You must print the top of all boxes first, then the next line of all of them etc.

If you had variable number of boxes to print this would be the solution:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    unsigned numberOfBoxes = 10;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; ++i)
        cout << "+---+" << (i == numberOfBoxes - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; ++i)
        cout << "|  " << i << "|" << (i == numberOfBoxes - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; ++i)
        cout << "|   |" << (i == numberOfBoxes - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; ++i)
        cout << "|   |" << (i == numberOfBoxes - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; ++i)
        cout << "+---+ ";
}
```

The `(i == numberOfBoxes - 1 ? "\n" : " ")` is there just to either add new line if the loop is on it's last iteration or add a space.

Answer (score 1):

An extension to Maros's answer:

If you want multiple rows and columns in case of printing in the form of a table or matrix:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    unsigned numberOfColumns = 2, numberOfRows = 2;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; ++j)
            cout << "+---+" << (j == numberOfColumns ? "\n" : " ");
        for (unsigned j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; ++j)
            cout << "|  " << j + (numberOfColumns *(i-1)) << "|" << (j == numberOfColumns ? "\n" : " ");
        for (unsigned j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; ++j)
            cout << "|   |" << (j == numberOfColumns ? "\n" : " ");
        for (unsigned j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; ++j)
            cout << "|   |" << (j == numberOfColumns ? "\n" : " ");
        for (unsigned j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; ++j)
            cout << "+---+ ";
        cout << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

You'd have to add a conditional if this matrix reaches beyond value 9.